# How to prove this limit of derivative

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, uniform-convergence

Here is a question that I need help to prove it.

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R} \in C^{\infty}$ be periodic of period $1$ and nonnegative. Show that
>   $$
> \dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{f(x)}{1+cf(x)}\right)\to0
> $$
>   uniformly in $x$ as $c\to\infty$.

My thought: I think it needs uniform convergence of function sequence to prove it. I know the derivative is
$$
\frac{f'(x)}{(1+cf(x))^2}
$$
but I am not sure how to do it exactly.

Comment: Hint: show that given any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a $C\in\mathbb{N}$ such that whenever $c > C$, it is the case that for all $x$, $\left|\frac{f'(x)}{(1+cf(x))^2} - 0\right| < \varepsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f(x)∈C^∞, f(x)⩾0$ and periodic, $f′(x_0)=0$ where $f(x_0)=0$. If $f(x)≡0$, then conclusion is obvious. So assume $f(x)≢0$.

Since $f′(x)$ is continuous and periodic, it is bounded, or $∃M>0, ∀x∈R, |f′(x)|⩽M$. Also for any $ϵ>0, ∃δ,0<δ<1, ∀|x−x_0|<δ$, there is $|f′(x)|<ϵ$, and
$$|f(x)|=|f′(t)(x−x_0)+f(x_0)|=|f′(t)(x−x_0)|<ϵδ<ϵ$$
where $|t−x_0|<δ.$

Now let $⋃\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}B(x_i,δ) (f(x_i)=0)$ be a cover of $[0,1]$.  Since $[0,1]$ is compact, there is a finite cover $A=⋃\limits_{i=1}^{n}B(x_i,δ)$. And there is
$$
\begin{cases}
|f′(x)|<ϵ, & \text{ for }  x∈A
\\
0\leqslant f(x)<ϵ, & \text{ for }   x∈A
\end{cases} 
$$
And
$$
\begin{cases}
|f′(x)|⩽M, & \text{ for }   x∈[0,1]−A
\\
f(x)⩾ϵ, & \text{ for }   x∈[0,1]−A
\end{cases} 
$$
Now
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{f(x)}{1+cf(x)}\right)=\frac{f′(x)}{(1+cf(x))^2}
$$
For $x∈A$
$$
\left|\frac{f′(x)}{(1+cf(x))^2}\right|⩽|f′(x)|<ϵ\hspace{5 mm} (c>0)
$$
For $x∈[0,1]−A$
$$\left|\frac{f′(x)}{(1+cf(x))^2}\right|⩽\frac{M}{(|cf(x)|−1)^2}⩽\frac{M}{(cϵ−1)^2}⩽ϵ \hspace{5 mm} \left(c>\left(\sqrt{\frac{M}{ϵ}}+1\right)/ϵ\right)
$$
So
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{f(x)}{1+cf(x)}\right)→0$$
uniformly for all $x∈[0,1].$

Since $f(x)$ has period of $1$, it is easily followed that the integral approaches to $0$ uniformly for all $x∈R.$

Comment: The argument about finite number of zeros of $f'$ is a bit strange. Think of two positive $C^\infty$-functions with finite support that are extended by zero between them. The points of this interval are zeros for $f'$ (continuum).

Comment: Smooth functions are NOT like analytic functions, they are much "nastier". For example, there is a smooth function which is [nowhere (real) analytic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function#A_smooth_function_which_is_nowhere_real_analytic). Actually any closed set $E\subset\mathbb{R}$ can be the zero set of a smooth function (see, for example, Exercise 5.21 in Walter Rudin's Principles of mathematical analysis).

Answer (score 1):

Denote $g(x)=\frac{f'(x)}{(1+cf(x))^2}$.

1. Since $f$ is periodic it is enough to prove convergence over the period (compact interval $T$).
2. Note that $f(x)=0$ implies $f'(x)=0$ (since $f\ge 0$ and differentiable).

Pick $\epsilon>0$. Any point $x$ with $f(x)=0$ can be covered by an open interval $E_x\subset T$ where $|f'(x)|\le\epsilon$. Denote $E$ the union of all such intervals. Clearly $|g(x)|\le|f'(x)|\le\epsilon$ for $x\in E$.

Now since the complement set $T_c=T\setminus E$ is compact, there exists $M=\max_{x\in T_c}|f'(x)|<+\infty$ and $m=\min_{x\in T_c}|f(x)|>0$ and we can estimate
$$
|g(x)|\le\frac{M}{c^2m^2}\le\epsilon\quad\text{for sufficiently large }c.
$$
Thus. $g\to 0$ uniformly when $c\to +\infty$.